# Installation of taichi legacy branch on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, c++, makefile

I am willing to work with code [spgrid_topo_opt](https://github.com/yuanming-hu/spgrid_topo_opt) which needs [taichi legacy](https://taichi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/legacy_installation.html) to be installed first.

To install taichi legacy following the instruction on the [page](https://taichi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/legacy_installation.html) I run the command

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yuanminghu/taichi/legacy/install.py
```

then `python3.8 install.py` which gives me the following error message :

```
In file included from /home/sourena/taichi/include/taichi/common/util.h:263,
                 from /home/sourena/taichi/include/taichi/util.h:6,
                 from /home/sourena/taichi/include/taichi/math/eigen.h:7,
                 from /home/sourena/taichi/include/taichi/math/svd.cpp:10:


  /home/sourena/taichi/include/taichi/common/meta.h:79:8: error: ‘void 
taichi::STATIC_IF::statement<Cond>::else_(const F&) [with F = 
taichi::imp_svd(const taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&, taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&, taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&, taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&) [with int dim = 2;T = double]::<lambda(const auto:25&)>; bool Cond = true]’, declared using local type ‘const taichi::imp_svd(const taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&, taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&, taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&, taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&) [with int dim = 2; T = double]::<lambda(const auto:25&)>’, is used but 
never defined [-fpermissive]
       79 |   void else_(const F &) {
          |        ^~~~~
    /home/sourena/taichi/include/taichi/common/meta.h:90:8: error: ‘void taichi::STATIC_IF::statement<false>::else_(const F&) [with F = taichi::imp_svd(const taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&, taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&, taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&, taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&) [with int dim = 3; T = double]::<lambda(const auto:25&)>]’, declared using local type ‘const taichi::imp_svd(const taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&, taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&, taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&, taichi::MatrixND<n, T>&) [with int dim = 3; T = double]::<lambda(const auto:25&)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
   90 |   void else_(const F &f) {
      |        ^~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/taichi_core.dir/build.make:193: CMakeFiles/taichi_core.dir/include/taichi/math/svd.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:96: CMakeFiles/taichi_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
  Error: Build failed.
  Error: installation failed.
```

The bottom line is I tried couple of different ways to download `install.py` and install taichi legacy with it but every time I get the same error message.

The code above is actually the very last fraction of the output, there doesn't seem to exist the log file of the whole output to share it with you here. I understand that it's difficult to find out what the problem is without a log file. So if you fellows can run the command and see if you succeed at installing the code smoothly or you get the same error message I'd appreciate it.

Could anybody be interested to have a look at this issue?

My machine is running on ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem.
It can be solved by installing taichi on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31570448)